# Facing issue while using npm custom library in project

Tags: angular, angular-library, spartacus-storefront

Requirement,

1. Need to create a custom library and this custom library should have the dependency of 3rd party libraries.
2. Use/install the above created custom library in the project and we should able to access the 3rd party Objects (Classes, components) from the custom library.

note:- consider spartacus like any 3rd party library.

Steps I tried,

1. created a library (spa-core)
2. added spartacus library dependencies in `package.json`(dependencies section) of spa-core
   [spa-core package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RreIp.png)
3. `npm install`
4. imported `BaseCoreModule` of spartacus in `spa-core-module.ts` file
   [spar-core module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eVAM.png)
5. build and published the library to npm.
6. created an another app and installed spa-core library in it using `npm install` command
   [package.json of the project where we installed the spa-core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYjDP.png)
7. imported spa-core-module in `app.module.ts`
   [app.module.ts file and imported the custom lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOBmd.png)
8. tried to extend a component of spartacus but not able to resolve the import. The component is not available from spa-core lib.
   [trying to access the Address.ts file from @sparatacus/core lib but its not showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l50cI.png)

[folder structure of node_modules in the project (after installing custom lib)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UAmR.png)

Comment: If Spartacus is a dependency for your custom then you can't access like you did. You need to export all the components you need from your library.